# flash as3 define variables before or in class constructor?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

what is the difference between something like

```
package {
    public class Myclass {
        var txt:TextField = new Textfield();

        function Myclass() {

        }

    }

}
```

and

```
package {

    public class Myclass {

        var txt:TextField;

        function MyClass() {

            txt = new TextField;
        }
    }
}
```

I know that when you set create a new object, the class constructor is run, like this:

var object:Myclass = new Myclass();

In the 2nd way, this creates the new TextField.

My confusion is that in the 1st way, when is the TextField being created? Will it set aside memory for TextField if I import the class into another class? What if it was a static variable instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Memory will not be allocated until you instantiate so in that regard it doesn't really matter.

If you use a static variable that variable will take up memory since that is not bound to an instantiated object but rather it is like a global variable in that class.

EDIT: Great clarifiation from **pkyeck** on how to best construct and initialize an object in the comments:
*in AS3 code inside the constructor is supposed to be slow - so it's best to create an init() method and do the instanciation there and just all the init() inside the constructor. Code inside the constructor is not optimized by the Just-in-time compiler (JIT). To use JIT optimized code there is the possibility to call a function out of the constructor. The code inside that function is then optimized again. taken from here: je2050.joa-ebert.com/files/misc/as3opt.pdf – pkyeck*

Comment: Also, make them private or public (or static) vars.

Comment: Yeah, or even protected. In general variables should be as private as possible and the use of getters and setters should be use to get/set values wherever it is possible.

Comment: Why is it considered good practice to instanciate in the constructor? In C# it's considered good practice to use field initialization (With ctor overloading the advantages are clear). In C++ it's also considered good practice to use the initialization list so the fields are only initialized once (they would otherwise get initialized to their default value before the ctor run anyway).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure actually. It is something I picked up many years ago when learning AS3 from lynda.com and gotoAndLearn() videos. I've since picked up Java in Computer Science at my university where they also claim it is good practice. I had no idea C++ and C# where different. If I could speculate it makes for cleaner code, at least in my opinion. You separate the declarations from the definitions and you give values to fields in the constructor which is the mechanism that creates the object. In my mind it seems more semantically correct but I guess it could differ from person to person.

Comment: in AS3 code inside the constructor is supposed to be slow - so it's best to create an `init()` method and do the instanciation there and just all the `init()` inside the constructor. 

`Code inside the constructor is not optimized by the Just-in-time compiler (JIT).
To use JIT optimized code there is the possibility to call a function out of the
constructor. The code inside that function is then optimized again.`

taken from here: http://je2050.joa-ebert.com/files/misc/as3opt.pdf